# Why assigning a function to a value in Scala using wildcard (i.e. underscore) returns a weird type?

Tags: scala, function

I'm trying to understand the rationale behind the wildcard (`_`) when assigning functions to values. What does it mean? And how does it work?

I'm getting a weird type when I do this:

```
scala> def maximize(x: Int, y: Int) = if (x > y) x else y
maximize: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> def max = maximize _
max: (Int, Int) => Int

scala> def m = max _
m: () => (Int, Int) => Int
```

Why did I get `() => (Int, Int) => Int` for m and what does it mean? A function chain? Can someone clarify for the layman?

Comment: I'll assume that's the difference between a *method* and a `Function1`

Comment: @Bergi silly additional question. I deleted. Thx!

Comment: It's called eta-expansion and it's used to convert a method type to an equivalent function type.

Answer (score 2):

"Wildcard" character here is used to convert a method reference into a function object.
`maximize` is a method, that accepts two parameters and returns an `Int`. `maximize _` is a function, accepting to parameters and returning `Int`.
Now, `max` is a method, that accepts no parameters and returns a function. Then `max _` is a function, returning a function . `m` s a method returning `max _`, so, it's return type has to be the same: a function returning a function with two parameters, returning an Int.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand the wildcard converting *methods* to *functions* (called [eta-expansion](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion)) we need to understand that Scala views named methods (such as `maximize`) and functions (all declared as `FunctionN` in Scala, e.g `Function1`, `Function2`, etc)  differently. The former doesn't actually have a value type. In the Scala Specification, they are listed under [*Non Value Types*](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#non-value-types):

> The types explained in the following do not denote sets of values, nor do they appear explicitly in programs. They are introduced in this report as the internal types of defined identifiers.

Since named methods don't have a value, Scala uses a convince syntax with the `_` wildcard after the named method do convert it to a method value, which is one of the `FunctionN` family. There also exists [implicit conversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#method-types) when assigning a method to a value:

> Method types do not exist as types of values. If a method name is used as a value, its type is implicitly converted to a corresponding function type.

Now that we have that covered, it rather simple to analyze the type you're seeing'

```
scala> def max = maximize _
max: (Int, Int) => Int
```

What you've done here is convert `maximize` from a non value method type to a *method value* of type `Function2`, which accepts two `Int` values and returns an `Int`.

```
scala> def m = max _
m: () => (Int, Int) => Int
```

Now, since `max` is already a `Function2` and we're creating yet another method value, we actually get a `Function0[Function2[Int, Int, Int]`, which is a function that generates yet another function and accepts no arguments and returns the former method.

If you're interested in a more in depth explanation, see [Difference between method and function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2529184/1870803)

Comment: `_` is not implicit conversion, it's pretty explicit, implicit is when you place method name in a function context. Also there is no such thing as "method value", `_` simply creates `FunctionN` object which calls method from its `apply` method.

Comment: @VictorMoroz I didn't mean to add that implicit in front of the conversion, that was a typo. Regarding method values, there is definitely such a thing. See [Scala Specification section 6.7 called "Method Values"](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#method-values)

Comment: You are right about the latter, I forget that Scala is notorious with inventing various terms. Syntactic sugar is called "method value" being in fact something that is usually called function with a closure.